# Reorder discrete variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to reorder the discrete variables that I have in ggplot2. I would like to display it like WTT, KOT, WTD, KOD in that order in the graph however, I am currently getting KOD,KOT,WTD,WTT in the graph. I have tried using match to manually order the dataframe but I don't see a change in the graph itself.

The data looks something like this:

```
type mean
WTT  100
KOT  110
WTD  1000
KOD  1300
```

The means will vary and I only care that the correct factors are paired to each other in a graph.

And the code I am primarily using is the following:

```
graph = ggplot(data = data_subset,aes(y = Mean, x = Type, color = Type))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward way would be to re-level your `type` variable:

```
graph = ggplot(data = data_subset,aes(y = Mean, x = factor(Type, levels = c("WTT", "KOT", "WTD", "KOD"), color = Type))
```